# A farmer buys $120$ head of livestock for a cost of $8000$

Tags: solution-verification, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

So I was again scrolling through the homepage of Youtube when I came across [this](https://youtu.be/bHU71_anRis) video by Cipher, which proposes the following question:$$\text{A farmer buys }120\text{ head of livestock for }8000\text{ dollars.}$$$$\text{Horses cost }100\text{ dollars each, cows }60\text{ dollars each, and a sheep }30\text{ dollars each.}$$$$\text{If the farmer buys at least one animal of each type and buys more horses than cows,}$$$$\text{what is the least number of sheep the farmer can buy?}$$While I was able to solve it (somewhat), I am not sure if the solution that I got is correct or if there is  an easier way that I would be able to solve it.

### **My attempt at solving it**

---

---

#### **Setting up the system of equations to solve the equation**

---

---

##### **Here is what I know**

---

---

A sheep can be bought at the price of $30$ dollars, a cow at $60$ dollars, and a horse at $100$ dollars. We also know that the total number of animals bought is $120$, and that the total cost is exactly $8000$ dollars, no more, no less. We also know that the number of cows bought is less than the number of horses bought, and that at least one animal of each type was bought. The system of equations can be visualized as:$$30s+60c+100h=8000$$$$s+c+h=120$$$$1\leq c\leq h-1$$$$1\leq c\lt h$$$$1\leq s$$$$\{c\lt h\}$$$$\text{ (What this does in Desmos is if }c\text{ is less than }h\text{ it returns a value of }1\text{, otherwise it returns a value of undefined}$$$$\text{As how the mod notation would be inputted into Desmos}$$

---

$$\operatorname{mod}(8000-30s,100h+60c)=0$$

---

$$\text{As how the mod notation would be represented usually}$$

---

$$8000-30s\pmod{100h+60c}=0$$But I'm pretty sure it's fine either way.

I actually wasn't able to make a whole lot of progress on my own, since Desmos, while it is great for creating sliders (and putting limits on the sliders) and for variable affecting large amounts of equations at once, it isn't really great for solving it otherwise, as while sometimes I was able to get the number of animals to add up to $120$, I wasn't really able to find any real way to get the remainder to equal $0$ or get the total cost to $120$. I actually got really desperate and plugged$$30s+60c+100h=8000$$$$s+c+h=120$$into [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=30s%2B60c%2B100h%3D8000%5C%2844%29+s%2Bc%2Bh%3D120) and got$$c=7n+2$$$$h=62-3n$$$$s=56-4n$$$$n\in\mathbb{Z}$$However, for this equation, I had to put the restriction that$$n\geq0$$Since $n$ cannot be a negative number, since plugging in $-1$ for $n$ gets us$$s=60$$$$h=65$$$$c=-5$$Which is not a possible solution. Now, all we need to do is plug in numbers for $n$ to find the minimum value for $s$ that is possible:

| $n$ | $s$ | $h$ | $c$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $56$ | $62$ | $2$ |
| $1$ | $52$ | $59$ | $9$ |
| $2$ | $48$ | $56$ | $16$ |
| $3$ | $44$ | $53$ | $23$ |
| $4$ | $40$ | $50$ | $30$ |
| $5$ | $36$ | $47$ | $37$ |

So far, so good! But what happens if we plug in $6$ for $n$?

| $n$ | $s$ | $h$ | $c$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $6$ | $32$ | $44$ | $44$ |

The problem with this is, even if we add $3$ horses and subtract $5$ sheep from our current total, even though all of the other previous conditions will be satisfied, we will only have $32+47+39=118$ animals, which fails to satisfy the requirement of having a total of $120$ animals, no more, no less.

The original equations:

[image]

The equations substituting $47$ for $h$ and $39$ for $c$:

[image]

Therefore, the minimum number of sheep that the farmer could buy is $36$

**My question**

---

Is there anything that I could have done to achieve the solution to the problem without having to use Desmos/Wolfram Alpha? If so, what could I have done?

Comment: Letting $(a,b,c)$ denote a viable triple, we have $a+b+c=120,\,100a+60b+30c=8000$.  We can use the first equation to remove $b$, as $b=120-a-c$.  Using that form for the second equation, and doing some arithmetic, we get $4a=3c+80$. Now, of course, many of the solutions to that will violate the condition that $a>b$ but it is still easy enough to list the options and check them.

Comment: @lulu Remember that $a\gt b$, $a-1\geq b$

Comment: I mentioned that.  There are so few cases that you can just go by inspection.

Comment: @lulu Sorry about that. I think it's just I read the first part of your comment and assumed you didn't know that $a\gt b$, $a-1\geq b$ but sorry about that

Comment: To make things even easier:  note that, intuitively, we want $a, b$ close to each other.  After all, if they were far apart, then you could always buy fewer sheep  and use the cash to buy more cows.  Thus we approximate by setting $a=b$ and get the solution $(44,44,37)$ which must be very, very close to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [solve](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve%5B+100+h+%2B+60+c+%2B+30+s+%3D%3D+8000+%26%26+h+%2B+c+%2B+s+%3D%3D+120%2C+%7Bh%2Cc%7D%5D) the system for $h$ and $c$, and get
$$h = \frac{3}{4} s + 20 \\
c = 100 - \frac{7}{4} s $$

So $s$ is a multiple of $4$. Moreover $\frac{3}{4} s + 20> 100- \frac{7}{4} s$ so $\frac{10}{4} s > 80$.  Maybe $s=36$ ?

Comment: Yes, $s$ would be equal to $36$